# PHP SQL output issue adding a third table to a query

Tags: php, sql

I am currently using this script below.

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `venues` as table1

LEFT JOIN `follows` as table2 on table1.venue_id = table2.venue_id

WHERE table2.user_id = $userid");
```

The tables have these fields:

Table1:

id, venue_id, user_id...

Table2:

id, venue_id, user_id...

The query above returns 5 records.

Now....

I need to add a third table to the above script Table3

Table 3 fields also contains id, venue_id, user_id... BUT I don't what it in the WHERE of the script.

I've tried adding a LEFT JOIN to the script above to add the third table like this:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `venues` as table1

LEFT JOIN `follows` as table2 on table1.venue_id = table2.venue_id

LEFT JOIN `stats` as table3 on table1.venue_id = table3.venue_id

WHERE table2.user_id = $userid");
```

The Stats table only contains 1 record.

Now, my problem is that the query above it's echoing the data on ALL the records and not just the one.

My question is...What I'm I doing wrong on the line I added:

LEFT JOIN `stats` as table3 on table1.venue_id = table3.venue_id ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I think you want to also join on the user_id. So

```
SELECT
*
FROM
    `venues` AS table1
LEFT JOIN `follows` AS table2 USING (venue_id)
LEFT JOIN `stats` AS table3 USING (venue_id, user_id)
WHERE
table2.user_id = $userid
```

is my solution

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to include record from table1 that have non null records in table3 then you need to use INNER JOIN and not a LEFT JOIN. See the MySQL documentation for [JOIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html)

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `venues` as table1

LEFT JOIN `follows` as table2 on table1.venue_id = table2.venue_id

INNER JOIN `stats` as table3 on table1.venue_id = table3.venue_id

WHERE table2.user_id = $userid");
```

The "INNER" is not needed explicitly. Joins are INNER joins by default

Comment: I've tried this one but it's only returning 1 record which is the record. I need it to display the 5 records but only the row that contains the data from stats to be echoed.

Comment: Ok. Then your question is incomplete. It sounds like your query is returning the correct data and your PHP script is not skipping over those you don't need to print. Can you add the PHP code that is echoing the data?

Answer (score 0):

You're not limiting the records at all. Use this instead:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `venues` as table1

LEFT JOIN `follows` as table2 on table1.venue_id = table2.venue_id

LEFT JOIN `stats` as table3 on table1.venue_id = table3.venue_id

WHERE table2.user_id = $userid AND table3.venue_id IS NOT NULL");
```

Comment: Just tried adding AND table3.venue_id IS NOT NULL but it's still giving me the same result.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `INNER JOIN` rather than an `LEFT JOIN`. See this `SO` [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549/difference-between-inner-and-outer-join) to make it clear or this [blog article](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)